# C# Forms application getting stuck On Top

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey all, real strange one here.

I have a c# 3.5 forms app running on Server 2008 R2.

The application is MDI, with about 15 active forms on the screen at a time.

Periodically, I get into a situation where the application is "Stuck" on top, that is to say that I can't alt+tab to any other form, the task bar appears, but the other form does not come forward.  The only way to get out of it is to hit Windows+D several times, this eventually shows the desktop, at which point I can clcik on one of the other running applications in the task bar.  When I click on another application, it comes on top, but my application also becomes visable.

This seems to happen about 25% of the time where the application runs, and there does not seem to be any rhyme or reason to it.

I am not setting any control to be Top-Most or anything like that.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: I'd thought I'd seen some sort of AlwaysOnTop or something involving the Z Order on .NET but I don't remember where so I can't really answer... Best thing to do when crap like this happens is restore from last server backup and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen this a few times with random applications, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

What I noticed is that the foreground app actually did lose focus, but the target app didn't *gain* focus. You can check this by seeing if the foreground app's title bar lost focus (grey, unless your colour scheme is different). To work around, switch *back* to the foreground app, then away again, and all should be well.